# Extreme values and monotonicity - understanding the relation between the the domain?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

My questions are very basic. I will not use *fancy math language*, because I am not familiar with it.

I have some function $f$ and want to calculate its monotonicity and local extreme values by using the derivative.

1. First I find the domain $D_{f}$.
2. Then I find the derivative $f'$.
3. Then I find the domain $D_{f'}$ of the derivative $f'$.
4. Then I solve the $f' = 0$ equation. **Let's say the solution is only one:** $x_{0}=15.$ (that is my local minimum or local maximum).
5. And finally I can find the monotonicity/extreme value(s).

I have few questions related to the domain of function $D_{f}$ and the domain of the derivative $D_{f'}$.

1. What if the solution $x_{0} = 15$ is in the domain $D_{f}$ but is not in the domain $D_{f'}$?
2. What if the solution $x_{0} = 15$ is in the domain $D_{f'}$ but is not in the domain $D_{f}$?
3. What if the solution $x_{0} = 15$ is in neither of the domains? (I'm pretty sure we ignore the $x_{0}$ solution then)

And, if that's not too much to ask:

1. The domain of $D_{f} = (0, 20)$ and the domain of $D_{f'} = (5, 10)$. When finding the extreme values/monotonicity, should I take into account only the mutual part of both domains?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why do you feel you need to find the domain of the derivative?

Comment: How could you solve $f'=0$ to get $x_0$ but not have $x_0 \in D_{f'}$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork not sure, university teacher demands it

Comment: @copper.hat so I only have to check if $x_{0}$ belongs to $D_{f}$?

Comment: @weno: I am not really sure what you are asking. You must have $D_{f'} \subset D_f$, otherwise it makes no sense. The derivative is defined in terms of the function's values. In general, unless the domain is 'nice' (the real line, an interval, etc) it is hard to give a nice characterisation.

Comment: Bottom line is this true? If I get a solution $x_{0}$, and it has to belong to the $D_{f} \cap  D_{f'}$ for it to be a valid solution?